# Cursor location scene Blender 2.8

Tags: python

There is no cursor_location property anymore now in Blender 2.8

So I tried

```
bpy.context.scene.location = [0,0,0]
```

But I again get an error that location is not defined for the scene. Any ideas how to get / set the cursor location in the lastest version?

Answer (score 5):

you can access to the cursor location with this code

```
bpy.context.scene.cursor.location
```

Comment: Ah my bad, forgot the cursor:-) Thx